# Cant get login box to the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

So I have been working on an HTML project and I decided to make a login page. Well, when I go to the stylesheet I write:

```
.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

which would usually put anything I wanted to the middle of the screen. But in this case, it put the login box to the top left of the screen and slightly out of it. So If anyone can please help me with my issue here that would be great... Thanks!

Comment: Seems like everything works just fine. Check semicolon after top rule.

Comment: Can you add your html code please

Answer (score 0):

You can give the class of `.login-box` fixed height and add a `;` after the `top: 50%`.

My English is not good, you can copy my CSS code to run again!

```css
.login-box {
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```